# Rendering theme_item_list items

Tags: 7, forms, theming

My module provides a simple block which needs to contain an unordered list with some images. 
From a block function, I am returning a renderable array:

```
$block['content'] = array(
    'list' => array(
        '#theme' => 'item_list',
        '#type' => 'ul',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => 'foo1'),
        '#items' => array(
          /* ...  what should go here? */
        ),
    ),
);
```

I would like to have some *renderable arrays* as items in the item list, but I seem to be unable to insert any arrays into the `#items` array.

The [Drupal 7 theme_item_list API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) docs says:

> items: An array of items to be displayed in the list. If an item is a
>   string, then it is used as is. If an item is an array, then the "data"
>   element of the array is used as the contents of the list item. If an
>   item is an array with a "children" element, those children are
>   displayed in a nested list. All other elements are treated as
>   attributes of the list item element.

I tried using both "data" and "children" elements, but I get either empty `<li>`'s or there is a word `Array` inside them.

**What is the proper way to do this?** Is theme_item_list the right/up-to-date solution?

Comment: `'#items' => array('data' => 'my data')` doesn't seem to really do anything more than `'#items' => 'my data'` (look at the code for [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7)). `'children'` is used specifically to create a nested list. I'm not sure why it's set up this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {

  // New array for readability
  $options = array(
    'path' => $image->url,
    'alt' => $image->alt,
  );

  // Push the image tag onto the items array
  $block['content']['list']['#items'][] = theme('image', $options);
}
```

Comment: This works and is easier than my answer. The only advantage of my answer is that everything is still in render arrays and can be manipulated by other modules/themes. If that isn't important to you, then this is definitely a good way to go.

Comment: I have been pondering this solution. As mentioned above, the only issue is not keeping the page structure as a renderable array - if other modules wanted to change the itemes, it would be much harder. But I guess it's good enough :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact same problem. From what I can tell reading the source code for [`theme_item_list()`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/rendering-theme-item-list-items) it can't use renderable arrays as items for the list. I ended up passing the renderable array with all the images to my own theme function to output the list. You can basically take your current code and change the `#theme` property to your custom theme function and add your renderable arrays as children of your `list` array. To make your function easier, you can add the `<li>` and `</li>` tags as `#prefix` and `#suffix` respectively to your image render arrays and call `drupal_render_children()` on your array, then you just wrap it in a `<ul>` and your good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following code and it render's the list after an ajax call

```
$test = array("type"=>"ol","items"=>array('data'=>'1'),'attributes'=>array());
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#item-'.$ot->nid,theme_item_list($test));
```

main difference is the "#", if you read the code of the function at [Drupal API function theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7), you'll see there are no hashes for the variables

```
    function theme_item_list($variables) {
        $items = $variables ['items'];
        $title = $variables ['title'];
        $type = $variables ['type'];
        $attributes = $variables ['attributes'];
    ... }
```